# How can private data be secured with OAuth2 authentication?

Tags: security, authentication, encryption, oauth-2.0

I am setting up a website to use Google's OAuth2 interface for user authentication. The website will store private data associated with each user - which I'm planning to encrypt.

If I implemented my own authentication method for the website, I could easily derive a key from the user's credentials (which include the user's password), allowing the data for each user to be strongly protected. But with OAuth2, I believe I can only receive an access token, granting that user permission for a period of time - the problem is that the access token value will change over time.

Is there a way that OAuth2 can provide me with an immutable secret tied to the user which I can use to derive a secure key from? Or is there some other method of creating a secure persistent secret using OAuth2?

--- Edit ---

In response to the questions and comments, here are some thoughts to consider:

- All user information should always be protected with strong encryption and user authentication - the reason we read so many news articles about website & database hacks is because developers say "do we really need to secure that" and then respond with "No - because no-one but us will be able to access the database, security is hard, etc". The hacker downloads the database *et violá*. Credit cards, email addresses, phone numbers, passwords, you name it, then become compromised.
- There are only two real secrets - one is a password stored in someone's head, the other is a strong random value that only the authorised user has access to (like a physical token). If you think a secure key can be derived from an email address alone, or that a secret needs to be stored in a database, you don't really understand security.

I guess what I was trying to discover was whether an OAuth provider can provide to the OAuth client an immutable value securely linked to both user and client - effectively, this would be a key that could only be unlocked by the OAuth provider using a combination of the user's secret (their authentication password) and the client's secret (used in the OAuth protocol). The client could then use this value to provide a reasonable level of security for the user's data.

Of course this implementation is not perfect from abuse, but implemented correctly, could provide a reasonable way to secure data whilst still using the good practices of the OAuth scheme.

Comment: I voted to close as too broad. However, I think the question is a good one and well asked. I'm never too sure about whether questions like this should be closed or not. The question is clearly from a programmer's perspective, but is it a programming question within the scope of stackoverflow?

Comment: Exactly how do you plan to *derive* a secret from something that is not secret, such as the user id? Remember that passwords and email addresses can and will change, the only constant is the user id and that is not secret. You would need to generate a random secret, and store that in your database, associated to the user id. But then the secret used to decrypt the data in the database is in the database as well, which makes it pointless.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get what you're asking for - if you need access to the data, then you need access to the key. The 'user's secret' and the 'client secret' aren't really different things. OAuth is used to determine that the user is who they say they are - you either have to trust that or not.

Comment: One extra thing you can do is to store a 'server encryption key' on the application servers, and combine this with the user's key to encrypt the data in the database. That way, if you have a database leak, assuming that they don't get your server key, your DB contents would still be secure.

Comment: @adelphus did you ever solve this problem? I'm trying to do something similar.

Comment: @MPLewis No - at least not in the way I wanted. In the end I went with per-user keys which I protect with a global server key loaded when the service starts - something close to the suggestion by Daniel Scott above.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the token is that you can then use the token to obtain information from Google about the user. During the initial authentication, you will tell the user, and google, that you want to access certain information about the user:

https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth

Assuming that the user allows you to access their information, such as their email address, you can then get their email address from google. Once you have their email address, you can generate a secret key for their user, store this in your user table, and use it to encrypt their data. Then, when they login again, you can lookup their email address and find their key.

Is there a specific need for the immutable information be 'secret'? Or is it just a key to identify a user?

If the information that you're storing is truly private, and you want to make it so that you can't access your user's data, then all you have to do is store the encrypted blob for your users. Once the user had downloaded their data, they can use their key to decrypt the data client-side.

Comment: But then the secret used to decrypt the data in the database is in the database as well. Doesn't that make the encryption pointless?

Comment: Ahh, so you want to make it so that the information is secured from you too? In that case, you should never have the key at all. All you need to do is store the data for the users. The secret key has to be stored/derived client side and the client can decrypt the data once they've obtained it from you.

Comment: Updated my answer to address this

Answer (score 0):

My first question would be: **Why do you want to derive your encryption keys from some tokens?**

The tokens and your encryption keys could remain independent and can be associated to a user identified by a unique id. User authentication can be done by whatever way you need either via credentials or open ID authentication or something else. But, once a user is authenticated, your decryption APIs can fetch the decryption key associated with the authenticated user and do whatever decryption it has to.

This way you can potentially allow users to tie multiple open ID accounts with the same user similar to what Stackoverflow does. I can associate my yahoo, facebook and google accounts with my Stackoverflow user and can sign in with any of those providers. I can disassociate those accounts any time I want. But that does not affect my Stackoverflow profile and data.

So, it is not a good idea to derive your keys from something that is not constant and keeps changing. Instead, keep them separate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand your point about separating  data encryption keys from authentication keys, but good security relies on the data encryption key only being unlocked from a trusted authentication secret - the point is how to do that. OpenID does not appear to give anything securely linked to a user that a client could use to unlock an encryption key. There is no security in "decryption APIs can fetch the key associated with the authentication user" without using a value that only the authenticated user (or a trusted provider like OAuth) knows.

Comment: I understand your point. I would further suggest as an extension to my earlier solution and that is to have a symmetric key encrypt the user data and the secure that symmetric key with password based encryption algorithm using the oauth/refresh token as the password. That way only the bearer of the token would be able to decrypt the symmetric key that would decrypt the user data. But, you need to re-encrypt the symmetric key with the new oauth token. Encrypting/Re-encrypting the symmetric key is simple and efficient than the data as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is constant secure (random) key for each user that you could get from authentication service that gives OAuth2 endpoint (in this case - Google).

OAuth2 protocol itself does not provide such value - Authentication server uses generated values that are not constant. But OAuth2 does not prohibit from giving this value from Resource server (together with user id, email etc). So basically OAuth2 lets you secure data in the way you want, but Google, which you currently use, does not give this type of constant random value.

Also note, that this would not work if you would let user relate few accounts, like Google and Facebook, as they would give different random keys.

If you derive secret from credentials, this would also mean that resetting password would reset user account.

Furthermore, if you encrypt data like emails in this way, it becomes impossible to decrypt them without currently signed-in user. So emailing newsletter becomes practically impossible. You cannot query the data in SQL also.

I could only suggest some countermeasures:

- Do not store sensitive data at all, or store it hashed. Passwords must be hashed, not encrypted. Do not store CC numbers, store tokens that represent them.
- Use encryption with key, stored in another data source. This adds at least some security - attacker must get not only DB copy, but also encryption key.
- As data is encrypted, storing it in database is no longer necessary. You can store encrypted data in files or some other source, where it is safer than in DB (no risk of SQL injections etc)

Answer (score -1):

I've been having this same issue. So far, I can't find a secure way around it.

Basically, we need a per-site randomly generated secret provided only with implicit flow that can be used to derive credentials to access systems and decrypt data.

Because I want to protect the data from myself, I could write the client to salt/hash the secret in two ways, one way to retrieve the data and another to decrypt it.

Alas, this is not the case.

I could derive credentials from things in the basic scope of the oAuth and that would protect the data against *me*, but that leaves the user wide open for cross-site vulnerabilities, and besides, personally identifiable information makes for a poor secret.

The best I got is to use implicit flow oAuth2 to acquire the user's email address, randomly generate a client side secret, and force the user to email themselves the secret (as a recovery key), then store the secret in localStorage. Salt/Hash the secret + oauth scope variable to derive the credentials client side (so the user must be logged in) needed to access, encrypt and decrypt data.

If the user ever clears their localStorage, they need to go click the link in the recovery email, which places the secret back into localStorage.

This places the scope of vulnerability back on the client, but is resistant to public machines (would have to know who was logged in last, and get access to the localStorage token), allows for recovery, and weakly requires the user to be logged in. Still vulnerable to plugin injection attacks and physical access + knowing the user.

**Update**: I have decided to use some oAuth extensions (hello.js, folder APIs) to store the keys in the user account as files. It requires some permissions and some APIs to implement, but appears to be viable.

Comment: This is mostly a question, dressed up as an answer. Please either post your own question (and delete this), or edit this until it answers the question. Deleting everything but your last paragraph and expanding on that might be a solution.

Answer (score -1):

> If I implemented my own authentication method for the website, I could easily derive a key from the user's credentials

This schema has a terrible weakness - if a user forgets /resets its credentials, the key is lost forever

> Is there a way that OAuth2 can provide me with an immutable secret tied to the user which I can use to derive a secure key from?

OAuth2 is an authorization protocol. It is not intended to give you any user secrets.

the Google's OAuth2 should provide a [user info service](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#obtainuserinfo)  returning username (email) and some id (sub).

However these are identity information, not any secrets. And mixing user credentials is imho bad idea (as already mentioned), using an external IdP (google) you will have no access to credentials tat all.

And now what?

My suggestion:

If you really want to encrypt user's data using a user-provided secret, let the user provide the secret or encrypt the data encryption key by the user itself (or using user's public key?). The user must be aware that if this secret is lost, the data will be unaccessible. It is quiet uncomfortable in long run. Some DMS systems use this approach to encrypt the stored sensitive documents.

if you want to encrypt data in rest (on the server, database), you may have an application specific key, imho best stored somewhere else (key vault, key management service,..). Indeed then there is a different risk profile (you have to protect the key,..) but it's much more convient for users. This is usually good enough along other security measures (even big enterprises don't ask for a separate password to encrypt your credit card number or email)